# Qt VS2012 Project Windows Deployment won't work

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have a VS2012 project working with Qt, OpenCV, Boost and some other libraries.

I installed Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL) to C:/Qt directory and configure VS project with work shared Qt DLL's. VS can run the project Debug and Release mode with no error.

But I can't run exe from directory. There's a deployment error. To make it work, I tried to put all DLL's to directory, contains these DLL's;

```
A2Engine.exe
cryptopp.dll
D3DCompiler_43.dll
gpsvc.dll
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
IEShims.dll
libcurl.dll
libeay32.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
libmySQL.dll
msvcp110.dll
msvcr110.dll
mysqlcppconn.dll
opencv_calib3d245.dll
opencv_contrib245.dll
opencv_core245.dll
opencv_features2d245.dll
opencv_ffmpeg245_64.dll
opencv_flann245.dll
opencv_gpu245.dll
opencv_highgui245.dll
opencv_imgproc245.dll
opencv_legacy245.dll
opencv_ml245.dll
opencv_nonfree245.dll
opencv_objdetect245.dll
opencv_photo245.dll
opencv_stitching245.dll
opencv_superres245.dll
opencv_ts245.dll
opencv_video245.dll
opencv_videostab245.dll
pthreadGC2.dll
pthreadGCE2.dll
pthreadVC2.dll
pthreadVCE2.dll
pthreadVSE2.dll
qminimal.dll
qoffscreen.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll
Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5OpenGL.dll
Qt5PrintSupport.dll
Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5Sensors.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5V8.dll
Qt5WebKit.dll
Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
qwindows.dll
ssleay32.dll
sysntfy.dll
tbb.dll
platforms/qminimal.dll
platforms/qoffscreen.dll
platforms/qwindows.dll
```

When I double click exe, nothing happens. Also dependency walker can't find any problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running it from `cmd` to see if anything is put to `stderr` or `stdout`, maybe put `getch()` as the first statement in the exe and try to attach to it with the debugger?

Comment: What is the command line output when trying to run the executable? Also, can you share a self-contained code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Try Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to check the missing file.
  **1.** Run **Process Monitor**.
  **2.** Click **Filter -> Filter**.
  **3.** Select **Process Name**, **contains**, enter application name, then select **Include**.
  **4.** Click **Add**.
  **5.** Click **OK**.
  **6.** Run your app.
  **7.** In Process Monitor, look for "**NAME NOT FOUND**" or something like that in **Result** column. And check the **Path** column for the file requested by your app. Make sure **Process Name** column is your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It seems there's ne output, it's not executing main(). Process Monitor is very useful but it couldn't find any  important errors. So still it won't work. Any other ideas with deployment?